# Internally Pulled-Up signal on STM32 interrupt pin?

Tags: interrupts, stm32cubemx, eclipse

I used 2 pins of STM32F103C8T6 as button interrupt which is both located on GPIOA port and 12 & 15 pins. the code compiled and loaded to the board successfully using STM32cubeIDE.
One of the input interrupts works perfectly but the other one (pinA12) is not. I measured the voltage of the pin using a multimeter...strange but there is 3.1 volts on the pin. It looks like the pin is pulled up internally.
by the way, the configuration of the pins is no pull up no pull-down and button schematic uploaded
[image]
has anyone faced such a strange condition before?

Comment: resolution of the picture requires magic glasses, please correct.

Comment: @Navaro replaced

Comment: What's the voltage on the other pin? What happens if you swap the connections to the encoder...which, if either, interrupt fails then? What happens if you replace the encoder with a couple of pushbutton switches? What do you mean when you say the interrupt doesn't work? Can you use the debugger to verify the values of the pins and track execution of the ISRs?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The interrupt works on pinA12 but the pin state is HIGH which means the program stuck in interrupt routine due to the 3.1 volts and me completely confused what is going on inside !! other pins act normal as their states

Comment: Are you using the USB interface?   Do you have behind-the-scenes software which would or previously run a custom bootloader which would?  PA12 is part of that so if you use USB it is not available for other use.

Comment: Have you read the errata if the conditions for PA12 bug apply in your case? Needs UART with handshaking and CAN with certain pin remap option.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed pa11 and 12 have slightly odd characteristics, which i think is due to them being usb pins and needing to be 5v tolerant. I'm not sure about this. I don't think they have the same esd arrangement.

Pull ups are 40kohm, so try attaching 40kohm pull down and see what it does.

Otherwise, the only other time I've seen this is after I've accidentally connected a pin to too many volts...

Also worth considering... Why are you using those pins? There are other pins with dedicated encoder inputs with timers attached e.g pb4 and 5 have timer 3 which can be set in encoder mode.

Answer (score 1):

The STM32F103C8T6 is used in the Blue Pill devices. If that is the one you have (i.e. not your own custom board) then it has 10k pull-up on PA12, which is actually connected to USB jack. Also note, that Blue Pills are shipped with bootloader that is using that USB interface.